# Can't set array values in select elements using Formbuilder in Angular

Tags: angular, formbuilder, formarray

I have this edit function. Only the select element does not update the value

invoice-update.component.ts

```
onUpdate(invoice) {
 console.log(invoice.customer)

 const control = <FormArray>this.form.controls['purchases'];
 control.controls = [];

 this.form.controls['$key'].setValue(invoice.$key);
 this.form.controls['customer'].setValue(invoice.customer);//this is the problem

 for (let i in invoice.purchases) {
   const product = (invoice.purchases[i].product);
   const quantity = (invoice.purchases[i].quantity);
   this.addPurchase(product);
   control.at(+i).get('quantity').setValue(quantity);
 }
}
```

Although the value is set in the select element, it does not allow updating the value, because it expects an array

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nologin-edit)

Comment: We can safely say that your stackblitz is far from a [mcve] Don't get me wrong, Great that you have a stackblitz :) but there is just too much code.

Comment: You are right. I just put the name of the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not updating because your Invoice model accept Customer object but you are passing just a name.

```
export class IInvoice {
  $key?: string;
  invoiceNumber?: number;
  createdAt?: string;
  modifiedAt?:string;
  uid?: string;

  customer: Customer; // Currently you are passing string to this key.
  purchases: Purchase[];
  totalPrice: number;
}
```

Replace item.name by item.
Update your select code from this:

```
 <select class="form-control custom-select" id="customer" formControlName="customer">
         <option [ngValue]="true">-Customer-</option>

         <option [ngValue]="item.name" *ngFor="let item of customerList" >{{item.name}} {{item.lastname}}</option>
 </select>
```

to this:

```
 <select class="form-control custom-select" id="customer" formControlName="customer">
         <option [ngValue]="true">-Customer-</option>

         <option [ngValue]="item" *ngFor="let item of customerList" >{{item.name}} {{item.lastname}}</option>
 </select>
```

And then it will work.

To set selected customer as default value in dropdown, you can use compareWith property. This property accepts function parameter. Just add following property in select tag:-

```
[compareWith]="compareFn"
```

And define **compareFn** function like this:-

```
compareFn(c1: any, c2:any): boolean {
   return c1 && c2 ? c1.name === c2.name : c1 === c2;
}
```

Now default customer should be set as expected based on selected data.

Comment: Thank. I try this, but now not set value selected when i make click  in the row

Comment: @RafaelCorzo . you can try to utilize compareWith property to select proper value 
https://netbasal.com/understanding-the-comparefn-input-in-angular-v4-4a401ef4fc4c

https://angular.io/api/forms/SelectControlValueAccessor

Comment: Is `IInvoice` suppose to be an `interface`?

Comment: Thank @Sumit_Parakh. My solution, complemenatry with the first answer, was this. compareFn(c1: any, c2:any): boolean {
    return c1 && c2 ? c1.name === c2.name : c1 === c2;
    }. Please add this code in your first answer and my vote is for you